# Example of a bicontinuous poset which is not jointly bicontinuous?

Tags: ct.category-theory, order-theory, general-relativity, domain-theory

Recall that a poset $P$ is said to be [continuous](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/continuous+poset) if, for every $p \in P$, the set $\{q \in P \mid q \ll p \}$ is directed with supremum $p$. Here $q \ll p$ is the "way below" relation (see the above nlab link for complete definitions). Following Scott, continuous posets are a widely used concept in programming language semantics.

Following [Martin and Panangaden](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0407094), a poset $P$ is said to be *bicontinuous* if $P$ and $P^{op}$ are both continuous. Most familiar continuous posets are not bicontinuous, but Martin and Panangaden give an interesting family of examples: if $M$ is a nice time-oriented Lorentzian manifold, then the points of $M$, ordered by the causality relation $J^+$ (where $p \leq q$ if there is a future-oriented causal curve from $p$ to $q$), form a bicontinuous poset. The way-below relation is the chronology relation $I^+$ (so that $p \ll q$ if there is a future-oriented timelike curve from $p$ to $q$).

In this example, the way-below relation coincides with the dual "way-above relation" (there is a future-oriented timelike curve from $p$ to $q$ iff there is a past-oriented timelike curve from $q$ to $p$). [Ebrahimi](https://dergipark.org.tr/en/pub/cankujse/issue/33134/368683) calls a bicontinuous poset with this property *jointly bicontinuous*.

**Question:** What is an example of a bicontinuous poset which is not jointly bicontinuous?

That is, what is an example of a poset $P$ such that $P$ and $P^{op}$ are both continuous, but where it is not the case that $x \ll y \Leftrightarrow y \ll^{op} x$ (where $\ll^{op}$ is the way-below relation on $P^{op}$)?

Answer (score 5):

It turns out there are some easy examples, as indicated by Keimel in [Bicontinuous Domains and Some Old Problems in Domain Theory](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1571066109004757):

- The unit interval $[0,1]$ is bicontinuous, but not quite jointly bicontinuous, because we have $0 \ll 0$ but not $0 \ll^{op} 0$ (and dually for $1$). Similar examples having to do with boundaries abound.
- If $X$ is a set, then the powerset lattice $P(X)$ is bicontinuous but not joint bicontinuous for $X$ infinite: we have $A \ll B$ iff $A$ is finite and $A \subseteq B$, whereas $B \ll^{op} A$ iff $B$ is cofinite and $A \subseteq B$. This example is harder to interpret in terms of "boundaries".